# PostgreSQL Security Audit

Tags: audit, databases

Could anyone provide a good resource or check-list for a security review of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The IBM wrote an article on hardening PostgreSQL: [Total security in a PostgreSQL database](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-postgresecurity/index.html). Should work as a check-list if to apply a bit another way of thinking about problem (switch on hacker mind).

From Owasp there are two papers, focusing on this field: [OWASP Backend Security Project Testing PostgreSQL](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Backend_Security_Project_Testing_PostgreSQL), that describes SQL Injection techniques within the scope of PostgreSQL and [OWASP Backend Security Project PostgreSQL Hardening](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Backend_Security_Project_PostgreSQL_Hardening), that describes requirements for secure PostgreSQL setup.

There is also a book, called "[SQL Injection Attacks and Defense](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597494240)". Well, the title itself describes the contents. (There is possible to see what is included in.)

PS: probably, it might be interesting to read also about Security-Enhanced PostrgreSQL: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SEPostgreSQL

Answer (score 5):

The US DoD has a general database security checklist and guide:

http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/checklist/

But not PostGres specifically.

Answer (score 1):

These are the only two books I know that have chapters on PostgreSQL security.

- The Database Hacker's Handbook, ISBN-13: 978-0764578014 (2005)
- PostgreSQL Administration Cookbook, ISBN 13 : 978-1-84951-028-8 (2010)

Comment: Confusion in relation to the term 'resource', I was using that to mean on-line resource (web pages to read etc.) But thank you for the sales pitch.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought you meant you were looking for people to help you. I've edited my original response accordingly.