# Secure 'pg_settings' for PostgreSQL

Tags: databases, audit

I have been looking for some kind of hardening guide towards PostgreSQL which I can use for a security audit of a PostgreSQL DB.

I came across this url, have checked the same. Anything more to this?:
[PostgreSQL Security Audit](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/postgresql-security-audit)

I am more specifically interested in the security flaws that could be identified from the settings that can extracted from pg_settings schema with context set to 'user'.

Do we have here any resource describing security flaws there?

Comment: The recent CVE-2018-1058 for PostgreSQL may be of interest.